# Why didn't Obito die after using Rinne rebirth?

Tags: naruto

In the Episode 391 of Shippuden, Reanimated Madara gets his own real body by forcing Obito via Black Zetsu to use the [Rinne Rebirth Jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique).

Similar to Nagato at the end of Pain arc fight, Why didn't Obito die since he used the same Jutsu as Nagato.

The wiki clearly states in exchange of own life, the Jutsu is performed.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I think Nagato died because he used all of his chakra and couldn't handle it but obito did survive even using rinne rebirth jutsu and tail beast extraction maybe it is due to fact that he attached himself to white zetsu which contains hashirama cell so he lived longer or it's just a plot hole.

Comment: Konan mentions that he will die due to low chakra but the wiki specifically says that "in exchange for the user's life" then it must be a plot hole. Whatever that can't be explained always links up to Hashirama or his cells.

Comment: One thing to remember is that the wiki can be wrong and I would take what happens in the series over what is written on the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chapter 657, right after Madara is brought back to life using the Rinne Rebirth jutsu, the scene moves to the Kamui dimension, where Zetsu confronts Kakashi, Minato, and a fatigued Obito.

Zetsu explicitly stated that Obito will die from using the jutsu. And then,

> [image]

So Black Zetsu was the reason Obito was able to postpone his unavoidable death.

Answer (score 0):

You don't die after using the Rinnegan Rebirth-if you remember correctly, Pain used the Rinnegan Rebirth too. Konan said that it would exhaust and possibly, kill him. So basically the art of Rinnegan Rebirth is not a new life in exchange for another one-its a justu which takes an enormous amount of chakra. You could die because of the exhaustion though. An example of this is that Nagato revived a whole freaking village while Obito just revived Madara Uchiha. Which should see a difference in terms of chakra

Comment: Can you provide any sources for this (chapter or episode number, etc.)?

Comment: Naruto Vs Pain-Naruto confronts him at his hidey hole.

Comment: It's clearly stated that the jutsu is devised at the cost of the user's life.

Comment: Again,it's the exhaustion you die from,not the sacrifice.Your wrongly interpreting what's stated.

Comment: Black Zetsu was giving Obito chakra to prolong his death.

Comment: I think someone who has read the Japanese Manga version can clarify this. Since sometimes, translations can be misinterpreted.
Also, I don't think pain died due to chakra exhaustion. If that is true he could have waited for his chakra to replenish or ask someone to heal him so that he can use the Jutsu without killing himself due to exhaustion.

Comment: There was nobody to heal him-he was only there with Konan(not a healer).Also,he had no time to replenish his chakra-remember he was fighting Naruto in his kyuubi form.If he had just waited,he would have died(I mean the Yahikos body which was being controlled).He had used too much chakra by then-that massive shinra tensei,also one chibaku tensei.He was really low on chakra.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Obito didn't die is because Black zetsu was saving him from dying them later he becomes ten tails jinjuriki which if we stayed in that form longer he would have been immortal then after ten tails was extracted he still had little chakra from each tailed beast. The reason he didn't die was because of Black Zetsu and especially ten tails. You see to perform rinne-rebirth you need especially high chakra which uchiha don't have ( I mean Uchiha have lots of chakra but not enough) so if an Uchiha more specifically Obito did it he would have died. Nagato ( Pain) is an Uzumaki and Uzumaki have lots of chakra. The reason Nagato died is because he had wasted lots of chakra in his battle vs Naruto and he also did the very powerful all mighty push which in my opinion drained maybe half of his chakra.So somebody like Obito,Sasuke,and Madara will die if they use rinne rebirth. The only people who would survive would be an Uzumaki, Nagato, and Naruto. Naruto would survive because he already has lots of chakra by being an Uzumaki then you add the Kurama he would have lots of chakra so he wouldn't die. Also in my opinion Naruto would be best suited for Rinnegan because he has 9 tails + Uzumaki chakra and rinnegan drains lots of chakra so it would be a best fit. Even Sasuke with his a lot of chakra will be drained if using a time space rinnegan jutsu so in my opinion the rinnegan would be very powerful in Naruto´s hands. Also the rinnegan that Nagato has was transplanted from Madara´s to Nagato because they choose him because he had lots of chakra.